# JPQL Aggregation return

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

Lets say I have the following JPQL query

`SELECT e.column1, e.column2, SUM(e.column3), SUM(e.column4) FROM Entity e GROUP BY e.column1, e.column2`

Obviously I wont be returning an Entity object but something a bit more complex. How do I return this in the method?

```
public List<???> query1() {

   Query q = entityManager.createQuery("...");

   List<Something???> list = q.getResultList();

   return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a query returns a `List<Object[]>`, where each element is thus an array of Objects. The first element of the array will have the type of Entity.column1, the second one will have the type of Entity.column2, and the last 2 ones will be (with Hibernate at least) of type Long (check with EclipseLink).

It's up to you to transform the `List<Object[]>` in a `List<Foo>`, by simply looping over the list of objects and transforming each one into a `Foo`. You may also use the constructor notation directly in the query (provided Foo has such a constructor), but I personally dislike it, because it isn't refactorable:

```
select new com.baz.bar.Foo(e.column1, e.column2, SUM(e.column3), SUM(e.column4)) from ...
```